# how to solve System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.' exception while generating random code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm getting System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.' while generating random numeric string using Random.

```
protected void btnOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string OrderId = "TEK" + CreateRandomCode(15);
}
public string CreateRandomCode(int codeCount = 15)
{
 string allChar = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
 string[] allCharArray = allChar.Split(',');
 string randomCode = "";
 int temp = -1;
 Random rand = new Random();//here I'm getting exception

 for (int i = 0; i < codeCount; i++)
 {
  if (temp != -1)
  {
   rand = new Random(i * temp * ((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks));
  }
  int t = rand.Next(10);
  if (temp != -1 && temp == t)
  {
   return CreateRandomCode(codeCount);
  }
  temp = t;
  randomCode += allCharArray[t];
 }
 return randomCode;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception is happening because your code is recursive and has no proper base case (exit condition). There is a maximum recursion depth you can have. If you go over that you get a `System.StackOverflowException`.

Modify your code to have a proper base case or change it completely. As far as I can tell you just want to generate a string which starts with `TEK` plus in your case 15 numbers attached to it.

The following creates a string containing 15 random digits:

```cs
public string CreateRandomCode(int codeCount = 15)
{
 string allChar = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
 string[] allCharArray = allChar.Split(',');
 string randomCode = "";
 Random rand = new Random();
 for (int i = 0; i < codeCount; i++)
 {
  randomCode += allCharArray[rand.Next(0, allCharArray.Length)]; 
 }
 return randomCode;
}
```